Данные при регистрации не отправляются в БД на хостинг
     **Файл registration.php
    **<h2>Регистрация  </h2>
                <form action="registration.php" id="form_login" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="name"maxlength="16" placeholder="Введите имя" required> <br>
                        <input type="text" name="phone"  minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Введите номер (7xxx...) " required>  <br>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите e-mail" maxlength="50" required> <br>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" minlength="8" maxlength="16"  required> <br>
                        <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Повторите пароль" minlength="8" maxlength="16" required> <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="button_registration"  value="Регистрация">
                 </form>
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password2'])) {
                    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']) {
                        $name = $_POST['name'];
                        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
                        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `phone`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', md5($password))");
                        echo '<div class="good"> Пользователь успешно добавлен <br> 
                        <a  href="join.php">Войти </a> </div> ';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo 'Пароли не совпадают';
                    }
                }
            ?>
файл обработчик входа 
**<html> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
</html>
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $phone = filter_var(trim($_POST['phone']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $passwordmd5 = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT *FROM `users` WHERE `phone`='{$phone}' AND `password`='{$passwordmd5}' LIMIT 1";
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
            $_SESSION['per'] = $result['per'];
            $_SESSION['phone'] = $result['phone'];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $result['name'];
            $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO events (text,phone) VALUES ('Попытка входа: удачный вход','{$_SESSION['phone']}')");
            if ($_SESSION['per']=="user") {
                echo "<script>window.location.href='lk.php'</script> ";
                echo 'Привет '.$_POST['login'].', права user';
            }
            if ($_SESSION['per']=="admin") {
                echo "<script>window.location.href='admin.php'</script> ";
                echo 'Привет '.$_POST['login'].', права user';
            }
        }else {
            $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO events (text,phone) VALUES ('Попытка входа: неудачный вход','{$_POST['phone']}')");
            echo'Неверное имя пользователя или пароль';
        }
    }
?>**
    Файл Join.php 
    <?php
      require_once 'connect.php';
      session_start();
    ?>
                <h2>Войдите в аккаунт </h2>
                <form action="add.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text"  id="fvxod" name="phone" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Введите номер (7xxx)"> <br>
                    <input type="password"  id="fvxod" name="password"  maxlength="16" placeholder="Введите пароль"> <br>
                    <input type="submit"  id="svxod"  value="Войти"> <br>
                    <input type="button" value="Регистрация"  onclick="window.location.href='registration.php'"> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>**
    файл connect.php 
    **<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'borhimnj';
    $pass = '';
    $db_name = 'bor`введите сюда код`himnj';
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
     if (!$connect) {
            die("Ошибка подключения: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    ?>**
    Использую хостинг Beget**


Вам надо в срочном порядке сделать две вещи: 1. Выкинуть, а лучше сжечь, тот учебник, из которого вы взяли весь этот ужас. И найти себе другой. В идеале - Джона Дакетта, но сойдет и Котеров. 2. Научиться описывать окружающую действительность словами. Даже если вы будете нам моргать, мы этого не увидим. Этот сайт передает только текст. И вам придется написать словами, почему вы решили, что "данные не отправляются" и что именно вы видите при этом на экране компьютера
